# Getting Remaining Text After Selection is Cut

Tags: ios, ios6, uitextview, uitextrange

Is there a simple way of getting remaining text after selection is cut?  Let me suppose that I have a textview control with "Hello, Jim" in it.  If "Jim" is selected, I want to store "Hello" to a variable, " without using [textview1 cut:self].  In the following code, I can get the other part.

```
UITextRange *selectedTextRange = textview1.selectedTextRange;
NSUInteger location = [textview1 offsetFromPosition:textview1.beginningOfDocument toPosition:selectedTextRange.start];
NSUInteger length = [textview1 offsetFromPosition:selectedTextRange.start toPosition:selectedTextRange.end];
NSRange selectedRange = NSMakeRange(location, length);
NSString *str = [textview1.text substringWithRange:selectedRange];
NSLog(@"%@",str);
```

Of course, that's the other part.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
NSString *remaining = [textview1.text stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:textview1.selectedRange withString:@""];
```

Comment: Thanks.  I wouldn't do that since it's possible that the textview content might contain multiple copies of selected phrase.

Comment: You are only replacing a range of text, not a text value.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's something like the following.  (Revised)

```
NSMutableString *str = [NSMutableString stringWithString:@""];
if (textview1.text.length > length) {
    [str appendString:[textview1.text substringToIndex:location]];
    [str appendString:[textview1.text substringFromIndex:location + length]];
} else {
    [str appendString:@""];
}
[self setText:str];
```